# MySQL Order by specific rows only

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that returns results in the following way:

```
id | count | type
------------------
1  | 1000  | 1
2  | 100   | 2
3  | 80    | 2
```

I would like to order the results only by rows where the `type` is `2`. The order of the other rows does not matter, although control over order by them could be useful down the line. The resulting order would therefore be `id = 2` then `id = 3` then `id = 1`. Is this possible without doing so in post-processing?

Comment: So you *want* to include those rows in the result but you want to *order them after* any rows with `2`? "Excluding from sort" does not make sense; you're sorting the whole set, every row must have some position within that set.

Comment: Yep, I want the result to include any `type`, but order by where `type` is 2

Comment: You should just have to add `ORDER BY type DESC` to your query, if there are more values for type then 1 & 2 you will get the greatest number ordering first though. Can you post your query so we can see what you have already please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to order rows with type `2` *first* and anything else after:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY IF(type = 2, 0, 1) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order by a column, it's:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY type ASC;
```

If you want to select only rows that `type` = 2, then it's:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = '2'
```

Comment: I want to order by the `type` column, but where `type` = 2, whilst still returning the other results.

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql useful to you

```
select * from table where type=2
union
select * from table
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `field`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY field(type,2,1)
```

Result:

```
id  count   type
----------------
2   100     2
3   80      2
1   1000    1
```

See demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200d1b/2)

**NB:** You can use as many parameters as you want.

Ex: `field(type,2,1,6,3,5,4)`

It will order the result in the order you specified in `field()`

If you don't want to specify all values, you can use `desc` at the end by specifying the parameters reverse.

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY field(type,3,2,5) desc
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0849/5)

Comment: Except you'll have to list all possible types this way... You could reformulate it to take advantage of `FIELD` returning `0` for unlisted values though.

Comment: @deceze: Updated my answer with `desc` at the end so that we don't have to specify all values. See this [**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0849/5). Thanks anyway!